# How to run multiple http requests sequentially multiple times

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm using jmeter for testing.  I have 1 thread group setup and multiple http requests under that thread group.  Jmeter will run those requests sequentially.  But how do I get them to run sequentially multiple times?

My setup is as follows:
Thread Group
-http request 1
 * variables
 * save file
 * results tree
-http request 2
 * variables
 * save file
 * results tree
-http request 3
 * variables
 * save file
 * results tree

I want jmeter to run them multiple times in order.  For example I want them to run twice.  So I want request 1 to run, then request 2 and then request 3.  Then I want request 1 to run, then request 2 and finally request 3.
[jmeter test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68wOJ.jpg)
[updated test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM6Ep.png)

[http request defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iXmf.jpg)
[http request defaults variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH77C.jpg)

[http request 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEt9i.jpg)
[http request 1 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUVUO.jpg)

[http request 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovyEh.jpg)
[htpp request 2 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5tqM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the loop count to 2 in the thread group and then it will run in sequence twice.

Please check below:-
[image]
[image]

Updated:-
[image]

Comment: I've tried that but it still isn't working the way I want. I should mention I'm using the CSV Data Set Config to pass variables to each call.  The variable file contains 4 records, 2 per request, each using different data.  But it seems like the 1st variable record is being used for each http request.  Then when it loops for the 2nd time it uses the 2nd record in the variable file.  How can I get it so that http request 1 loop 1 uses the 1st variable record, http request 2 loop 1 ruses the 2nd record, http request 1 loop 2 uses the 3rd record and http request 2 loop 2 uses the last record

Comment: Added image of jmeter request to main questions

Comment: Add two csv with two variables for each for both the request. Then, 1st run will pick first value from respective csv's...Check the updated snapshot.

Comment: Ok I tried that, I don't get the results your snapshot shows.  http request 1 will run and grab the first row of variables from it's file, then http request 2 will run and it will grab the 2nd row of variables from it's file.  I added another screen shot.  Is it because I'm using the same variable names for each request?  Is it because I have a http request defaults setup using those variables names (so I don't have to fill them out on every single http request)?  Are there special settings on the csv data config I need to set?  This isn't making sense to me

Comment: Do not use same variable names in csv as well as in sampler.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  If the variables names aren't the same, how do they get populated correctly at run time into the http request?  I'm sure there is something in my setup, due to my lack of knowledge of jmeter, but I can't be the only person who's wanted to do this, must be a way.  I attached more images in the original post to show my exact setup.  If you could let me know what's wrong with it and why this isn't working the way I want, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Corey, You are using HTTP Request default to send the parameters. Instead, used HTTP Request i.e. "Run Billing and Listing" parameters area to send the parameters with two different csv config. HTTP request default will send the same information to all the request. This is not what you need. You need to send two request with same parameters but different inputs. In HTTP request default, use only those parameters which are common in both and need to be send with every request like server,port number etc and does not required different input like your scenerio.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, now I know what I was doing wrong.  I got it working, thanks so much for you help.